# Fill cells in one tab with specific values collected from other tabs in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to fill the cells range in one tab with the specific values collected from other tabs in my google sheets. However, I can't manage to write a correct script for it.

**Here's a more detailed explanation:**

I have several tabs in my google sheets document that represent a month of the year, i.e. they're named as `July 2017`, `December 2016` and so on. Also I have two other tabs that are named `Graphs` and `Blank`.

Every month tab in its `N6` cell has a value like this: `Balance 33050,32 UAH` (the number may vary from tab to tab).

**What I'm trying to do:**

I need to collect the `N6` values from all my month tabs and fill this values into the `A` column of the `Graphs` tab. Then I need to build a graph out of all the values I've collected. But the main problem for now is collecting the values correctly.

I've tried to write a script for this, but it seems that I do something incorrectly. I'm quite new to the google script stuff, so maybe I'm missing something simple here.

Here's my script:

```
var months = [
  "january","february","march","april","may","june","july","august","september","october", "november","december"
];

var graphSheetName = 'Graphs';
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var graphSheet = ss.getSheetByName(graphSheetName);

// this function tells if the name of the tab refers to one of the month tabs.
function isMonthSheet(name) {
  return matchInArray(name, months);
}

function matchInArray(string, expressions) {
    var len = expressions.length,
        i = 0;

    for (; i < len; i++) {
        if (string.toLowerCase().match(expressions[i])) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// This function runs on every edit of the google sheets document.
// It should fill the cells in the `Graphs` tab.
function getMonthsTotals() {  
  var sheets = ss.getSheets(); // get all tabs
  var values = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; ++i) {
   var sheet = sheets[i];

    // if it is a month tab, collect the N6 value into the `values` array.
    // "Balance 33050,32 UAH".slice(8,-4) --> "33050,32".
    if (isMonthSheet(sheet.getName())) {
      var value = sheet.getRange('N6').getValue().slice(8, -4);
      values.push(value);
    }
  }

  // fill the `Graphs` tab with the collected values into the `A` column.
  var rangeStr = 'A1:A' + values.length;
  graphSheet.getRange(rangeStr).setValues(values);
}
```

---

As I've already said above, I'm quite new to google sheets scripting, so I'm not very familiar with debugging in it as well, so my method is using the `toast` function. Hence, I can't really provide much of info as for how the script is actually running.

I seek advice and help on how to correct my script to make it run correctly.

Comment: "it seems that I do something incorrectly." does not help in diagnosing the problem. How is the result different from expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function gatheringValues()
{
  var months=['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','December'];
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var allsheets=ss.getSheets();
  var n6s=[];
  for(var i=0;i<allsheets.length;i++)
  {
    var month=allsheets[i].getName().split(' ')[0];
    if(months.indexOf(month)>-1)
    {
      n6s.push([allsheets[i].getRange('N6').getValue().slice(8,-4)]);
    }
  }
  var graphsht=ss.getSheetByName('Graphs');
  graphsht.getRange(2,1,n6s.length,1).setValues(n6s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so the problem was with the function `getRange().setValues()` function inside `getMonthTotals`.

It expected to get the `Object[][]` type but instead was getting a simple array of strings. I've managed to overcome this problem by looping and using the `setValue(string)` function instead of `setValues(Object[][])`.

Here's what I've come up with:

```
function getMonthsTotals() {  
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var values = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; ++i) {
   var sheet = sheets[i];

    if (isMonthSheet(sheet.getName())) {
      var value = sheet.getRange('N6').getValue().slice(8, -4);
      values.push(value);
    }
  }

  for (var i = 1; i <= values.length; ++i) {
   graphSheet.getRange('A' + i).setValue(values[i - 1]);
  }
}
```